# How to assert once with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pytest

How can I make the following code more pythonic? so I can combine if/else and 2 assert statement into one line?

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('para', [1, -1, 0])
def test_xxxx(self, para):
    def test(value):
        return False if value >= 0 else True

    if para >= 0:
        assert test(para) is False
    else:
        assert test(para) is True
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 8):

Be explicit and simply write out 3 assertions with the inputs and expected outputs (note: I took your function outside your test and gave it a clearer name).

```
def my_func(value):
    return False if value >= 0 else True

def test_my_func(self):
    assert my_func(1) is False
    assert my_func(-1) is True
    assert my_func(0) is True
```

This is "being pythonic" because as PEP-8 says, "explicit is always better than implicit". When you're dealing with tests, writing as little functioning code as possible is more important than writing fewer lines.

Three explicit assertions is far less likely to fail than a wacky parameterizing loop or trying to make it a one-liner.

Comment: It's either `my_func()` or `test()`. Which one? I'd also recommend to rewrite `def my_func(value): return value < 0`.

Comment: @phd good catch on the assertions (I forgot to save my change the first time). However, I don't want to change the OP's logic; The point was to move the function they're testing outside the actual test.

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` function determines whether a value is negative or not, which can be simplified into the `is_negative` function below (which is also more pythonic). Since you asked specifically for `if - else` oneliner, I also added the second test function, but that is just more verbose (and less pythonic) way to rewrite the first one.

In this case the function is extremely simple, the tests have no real value, as they just do the same and assert that the results are the same, but I assume you have more complex case and the provided code is just a demonstration.

```
def is_negative(value):
    return value < 0


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", [1, -1, 0])
def test_is_negative(param):
    assert (param < 0) == is_negative(param)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", [1, -1, 0])
def test_is_negative2(param):
    assert is_negative(param) is True if param < 0 else is_negative(param) is False
```